# android:textColor not working after support library 23.2.1 update

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design

I have a bunch of card views with text views inside of them, like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/crdView"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    card:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
    card:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner"
    card:cardBackgroundColor="@color/darkorange">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/text" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I've set the textColor attribute to white, as you can see there. But when I run the app in any version of android that's not 6.0, it has no effect on the text view's text color at all.

So far I've tried:

- changing my `buildToolsVersion` in gradle
- changing the version of the support library itself in gradle, going back as far as `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'`
- several complete cleans and rebuilds
- trying to set it programmatically, which works (but having to do that for 20+ activities with a lot of text views is not feasible at all)

Is there anything that I'm not doing right? Should I be setting a different attribute now?

EDIT: Here's my build.gradle if it helps:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        generatedDensities = []
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        signingconfig {
            // sanitized
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 16
        versionName "1.1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    // other libraries
}
```

Comment: try this in build.gradle under android tag: 
aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal I've updated the question to include my build.gradle.

Comment: show your styles.xml and manifest

Comment: @ArnavM. Here is the styles.xml : https://gist.github.com/theabhishek2511/e00ad24f1669b046a407ec369123ddee . I cannot post the manifest due to company policy, what should I check for in the manifest?

Comment: <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item> in the themes might help but it will change textcolor everywhere...try change color and running again on 6.0 and make sure you're using the same cardView.

Comment: @ArnavM. yes, that will change the color everywhere, which is not what I want - I have some textviews that need to have the default black text. I can change the text color on 6.0 just fine, on lower versions though it does nothing.

Comment: is the text visible?

Comment: does it matter if the text is visible or not? i just want a white textview, how hard can it be?

Comment: I have the same f****** issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please find my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36545237/343201

Apparently the issue is due to Mavel Local Repository. Downgrading it to version 26 does the job.

Comment: Yeah, this worked, thanks! I'm stupefied though, how does something like this make its way into release??