# How to use custom inline attributes in xml layout files for customizing style of views

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-appcompat

since when I upgraded the Android Support Library, I'm struggling with setting custom colors for buttons, textviews and other views. Apparently, inline attributes get overridden by values defined in the application theme.

I have defined an application theme in values/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

For instance, in my layout files, I set background and text colors of a button as follows:

```
<Button
...
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
...
/>
```

And here's how I define colors in colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#0066FF</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#004AFF</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="background">#CCCCCC</color>
    <color name="text">#555555</color>
    <color name="green">#009900</color>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="orange">#FFA500</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="brown">#7A5230</color>
    <color name="goalkeeper">#FFA500</color>
    <color name="defender">#007c09</color>
    <color name="midfielder">#1d8dc0</color>
    <color name="attacker">#aa0a1c</color>
</resources>
```

Also, in the Manifest I correctly set the theme:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:theme">
```

In the preview everything looks good, however when I launch the app in the simulator all inline attributes are ignored and overridden by the values defined by my application theme. Why so? Why are inline attributes ignored? Is there a way to avoid that?

UPDATE: I'm currently following the solution pointed out here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203136&q=-has%3Ablocked%20reportedby%3DDeveloper%20attachments%3D2%20label%3AComponent-Support-Libraries&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened It may be an issue caused by a bug in Maven Local repository

Comment: It would be nice if you can post your colors.xml, so we can check it out if colors syntax wrote correctly,

Comment: Also you can use android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary" instead of android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary". So it gets color up to your styles. Also make sure you have correct theme set from your manifest.

Comment: @EmreAktürk I added content of colors.xml. The problem is that I would like to use arbitrary colors for buttons, so if I use android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary" I would be limited to theme colors. Also, custom colors work well if I use them programmatically outside layout files. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the cause, hence fixed the issue :-)

Apparently the version 29 of the Maven Local Repository (aka m2repository)is buggy, as pointed out here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203136&q=-has%3Ablocked%20reportedby%3DDeveloper%20attachments%3D2%20label%3AComponent-Support-Libraries&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened and here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203546

The solution is simple: just downgrade to version 26, which can be downloaded here http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r26.zip

Comment: Hi, sorry, rookie question, how do I downgrade the repo using this file?

Answer (score 0):

tools:replace="android:theme" this tag is used for manifest merger to tell how to handle spesific cases.

Looks like it changing your theme attribute in manifest at your final product. Can you try to remove that?

For more information you can check [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger)

Comment: In my project I'm importing another module which has its own manifest. If I juste remove that tag I get an error. How should I change it?

Comment: Ok. Normally your others modules shouldnt have application tag in manifest. Esspcially it is library that you found from web. You might imported an sample application. If so basicly remove sample module. Library module is enough for you to use it. Another way to remove android:theme attribute from your module that makes error.

Comment: If you found library from web, you can send me a link so i can check how you should import

Comment: Does it opens an activity from arena deamon?

Comment: Ok, lets try to remove theme attribute from arenadeamon manifest?

Comment: If it works, you can add removed theme atribute to activity in arena deamon manifest. So basicly, we declare theme to a spesific activity instead of whole application which can conflict with ours

Comment: I'm trying. I'll keep you posted. Thanks

Comment: Bad news. I tried everything (even defining my own styles and applying them to buttons and textviews) but nothing worked. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have your project in github it any other version comte ol system? İ would like to check it out

Comment: Found the solution. Read my answer.

Comment: Quite happy that you found answer